# Correct Spot Healing Brush imperfections and tattoo

Tags: adobe-photoshop

(this is on adobe photoshop )
I wanted to modify this pic

[image: image i will midify]

However, after deleting the stars, I got this 
[image]

As you can see there are some black marks... what should i do to get rid of them ?
thx all

Comment: Hi Namrouch, What method have you already used to remove the black marks?

Comment: Healing tools, blur methods... there are a lot of ways.

Comment: Well i used the patch as well as the Spot Healing Brush, but it's kinda useless to reuse them now, they just deepen the problem. Maybe I used them wrong ?

Comment: Are you working with an index mode gif or is that just what you've posted here?

Comment: I justed posted a gif here because of it's small size

Comment: It's difficult to experiment with the gif due to the dithering. In general, the healing tools or patch tools should work. In most cases small corrections work better than trying to correct it all at once.

Comment: Keep going, blur to soften it up and use HSL passes to get back the texture

Comment: Have you tried going back to the original and retrying the removal process? You may need to try different methods of removing the dark stars. That will likely be easier than trying to fix the already botched copy. If you can, and like to pursue this path, I will provide recommended steps in an answer.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63138/real-non-destructive-way-of-clonestamp-tool-in-photoshop/63142#63142

Comment: @Namrouch Please don't forget to upvote and pick an answer if they have helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some techniques that could help: http://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-techniques-for-retouching-skin--cms-22293

I would recommend creating a duplicate of the background, using a heavy Gaussian blur on that layer, creating a layer mask to brush out the areas you don't need, and then lowering the opacity of that layer until the skin smoothes out.

Answer (score 1):

## Practice

You are using the correct tools, you merely need to get more proficient with them. Slow down, take more care when using them, and learn to tweak settings to your needs.

There's rarely a "one button" solution. Everything requires practice.